# Passing HTML code to template in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

My `data` function is like below

```
data() {
   return  {
       message: ''
   }
},
```

I have method like below

```
adddress () { 
   for (let value of Object.values(response.body.errors)) {
      this.message += '<li>'+ value +'</li>'
   }
},
```

I am trying to display `message` like below

```
<template v-if="message">
   <div class="ui red message">
       <ul>
         {{ message }}
       </ul>
   </div>
</template>
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [raw HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) (`v-html`):

```
<template v-if="message">
   <div class="ui red message">
     <ul v-html="message"></ul>
   </div>
</template>
```